# Python: Open CSV and convert first column from Unix Timestamp to human date

Tags: python, csv, unix

I am a newbie and starting programming with python.
I Have a CSV file with two columns. The first is with Unix Timestamps. I want to convert this into human date using pandas.
What I have till now:

```
import _csv
import pandas as pd

out=open("data_magnetic.csv","rb")
data=_csv.reader(out)

data=[row for row in data]
out.close()

a = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(a)
```

Also I have found the code in stackoverflow to convert single values from Unix to human date:

```
import time

print(
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1475761269977") / 1000))
)
```

How can I combine this and run the code on the column in my CSV file?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are two columns in csv you can apply a conversion function in comprehension on first index of data row.

```
import time
import _csv
import pandas as pd

def convert_from_unix_stamp(raw):
   return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int(raw) / 1000))

out=open("data_magnetic.csv","rb")
data=_csv.reader(out)

data=[(convert_from_unix_stamp(row[0]),row[1]) for row in data]
out.close()

a = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(a)
```